# With Drush, what's the correct procedure to install Commerce Kickstart, Drupal, and the sample store data as a new site?

Tags: commerce

In my opinion, the install documentation is a bit lacking when answering this question.

http://www.drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/install

I want to avoid the browser all together and install commerce_kickstart and configure the sample store all via the command line with Drush.

What's the correct way to do this? Download Drupal; Download commerce_kickstart which creates a profile directory, and then 'drush si commerce_kickstart ... ' ?

Answer (score 1):

Commerce Kickstart differs from the standard core installation profile, by having extra installation steps. These steps are illustrated in the offical Commerce installation docs - they ask questions about store features and whether or not to install the sample store data.

Installation via drush does indeed work, however it does NOT offer these extra-step choices to the user. Instead it assumes you want the sample store.

So installation via drush is straight-forward. Assuming you have downloaded and unpacked the distribution archive file, just `cd` to the Drupal root, and run `drush site-install commerce_kickstart`.

Take some time to review the options described by `drush help site-install`. Most likely you will need to pass in a few more options, such as database credentials. A typical installation command will look something like this:

`drush site-install commerce_kickstart --account-pass=admin --account-name=admin --db-url=mysql://root:pass@localhost/db_name --notify`

Note that the Commerce Kickstart takes a lot more time than the standard core install profile. It sets up over 100 modules, several content/product types, and imports the sample store data. `drush site-install` will tell you "This takes a few seconds...", but it took 10 minutes on my machine :-)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install Drupal and commerce kickstart separately. Commerce Kickstart distribution itself contains the latest Drupal.

Only command that you need is drush dl commerce_kickstart

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question about installation of the sample store. `drush dl` just downloads the distribution; it doesn't carry out the installation.